# Keep spolier answer showing after mouse move.

Tags: html, css, element

I'm trying to make a basic FAQ of sorts using a simple click on element to reveal the answer to the FAQ. Spoiler..
I have found a really handy piece of coding, but everything I try I cannot prevent the mouse hover from making the answer disappear. 
I need the answer to remain on the page until the user is ready to click the next FAQ.

I hope someone can help, thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<p><b>This is an FAQ</b><br />
<p>This is also FAQ click below for the answer</p>
<div class=spoiler><div>
My hidden text
</div></div>
</body>
</html>

.spoiler { display: relative; cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; }
.spoiler:before { content: "Answer:"; position:absolute; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; color: #2C3635; }
.spoiler > div { cursor: default; top: 0px; display: none; position: relative; right: 10px; top: 20px; border: #A6B2A6 1px solid; background: darkgrey; padding: 0px 10px 15px 10px; border-radius: 4px; }
.spoiler > div:before { content: ""; display: block; width: 100%; height: 20px; margin-top: -20px; }
.spoiler:active > div { display: block; }
.spoiler > div:hover { display: block; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g9b3ugzh/

Comment: You will want to use what is known as "the checkbox hack". See this example: http://dabblet.com/gist/1507019 However, this is nearing the edge of what CSS should really be used for and you may choose to opt for a JavaScript solution instead.

Comment: @spacerGIF that's brilliant! Thank you. I totally get what you mean with regards to the edge of CSS and can understand that JavaScript would most likely be the next step up from here. 
To be honest, the style and ease is what I am looking for, for a simple HTML drop down FAQ, for some sites I run and need to add FAQ's ready for GDPR et al. 
This is perfect, how can I mark this as a solution?
Appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Since I left a comment rather than an answer, you can't mark it as a solution. The two answers on here look good though - definitely more precise than my vague paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML details and summary elements are perfect for this. The basics without any CSS required are as follows:

```
<details>
    <summary>Answer:</summary>
    <p>My hidden text</p>
</details>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xpd9014h/)

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about this but then saw they're not supported in IE (of course..!) but also Edge too. Would you think this is a better solution all 'round then?
I appreciate your time. :)
I can't vote it as have to have a minimum of set upvotes. Crazy.. sorry.

Comment: There are probably polyfills for making it work with MS browsers.

Comment: Yes I should imagine there's something there in place for it. Will try it and test it.

Comment: Yes, handily there's a polyfill ([here](https://github.com/javan/details-element-polyfill)).

Comment: @Willans brilliant, thank you! Am sure that will help many others too. :)

Comment: Oh wow, I wasn't aware of the `<details>` tag. That's awesome and I think I'll use it in future projects! Internet Explorer support... meh, it's a dying browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the code, it is a JavaScript solution, in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9b3ugzh/15/) a go.

```
var spoiler = document.getElementsByClassName('spoiler');

  var showSpoiler = function() {
    this.classList.add("show-spoiler");
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < spoiler.length; i++) {
    spoiler[i].addEventListener("mouseover", showSpoiler);
  }
```

Had to disable and amend some CSS too though, to make it work:

- Took off `position: absolute;` from `.spoiler:before`
- Took off `top` declarations from `.spoiler > div`
- Removed the `:hover` and `:active` states on `.spoiler`

Comment: Very clever, thank you. 
So am I right in saying the :before was the line that was making the text disappear after mouse move? 
Thank you again, very clean :)

Comment: So it was actually the `.spoiler:active > div { display: block; }
`. The reason behind this is that `:active` refers to a state where the current element is is clicked, mainly used for `<a>` but can be used for other elements too.

I'm not too sure when this `:active` state gets turned off, but in this case it was getting turned off as soon as the mouse left the element. The `position: absolute;` on the `:before` was just basically hiding the previous `.spoiler` behind the latest one making it impossible to interact with.  :)

Comment: thank you, appreciate the explanation. I knew it was :active but coouldn't work out precisely why or what the reason behind it was. Been doing this years and as the saying goes; every day is a school day. Thank you for the explanation. Amazing what stares you in the face sometimes. I tried all ways with/without but couldn't prevent it from happening and yet it's so simple. Anyway that's great thank you! :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. It's just one of those things that you have to do a few times to remember what might work and what might not. :)